Modifying a PWM signal to control xmas lights
I have a xmas light strip (24V lights half of the lights and -24V lights the other half) that is controlled via a L298N H-bridge. Currently I'm controlling them by creating a 50% duty cycle PWM signal (let's call it L1) and using a not gate for an inverse signal of it (call it L2) and feed L1 and L2 to 2 different 2n2222 collectors and feed the base pins with the actual on/off signals that determine whether I want either half of the lights to light up. This system works fine for a simple on/off system that controls each half individually.
Now, I wonder if it would be possible to create dimming control for each set of lights individually. Basically this would mean changing the PWM duty cycles, but as I can't have simultaneous HIGH-signals going to the L298N (as it would just turn both lights off), I need to the L1+L2 signals to be synchronized.
I'm thinking AND gates and separately controllable PWM signals with higher frequency for both of them. Would this be the sensible solution? I'm using an Arduino for this and I've already realized I need to create the main PWM signal outside the Arduino, as I will also be using the tone library to create horrible square wave muzak (think motion sensors and rickrolling with square wave signal feeding to a car amp and speakers and you're getting my idea).
Am I on the right track or are there other more sensible ways to achieve individual dimming control?

Hmm. My idea could be possibly created with PCA9625 or similar LED controller circuit. I did hope that I would need to avoid to buy more parts and just use the basic stuff I already have (such as 555s), but this doesn't really seem to be a valid option.

you will need more than one pwm channel. you might want to use direct port access to create the signals manually, which would let you add the dead time you need where both hbridge inputs are matching instead of inverse.
